# EF Insert Array into db With View

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have something to ask , i 'm going to create a simple application that store value of student Below is my class which i have tried .

```
Class Data{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int[] ValuesStudent{get;set;}
```

}

And below is example of the data

```
id = 1 
Name = Jhon 
Values = 9,8,7,5,9,7,4,6,4


id = 2
Name = Uncle 
Values = 4,7,8,4

id = 3 
Name = Jhon 
Values = 9,8,7,5,9,7
```

as you can see above example of the data i can insert multiple value as i need, Student has taken 3 examination so i must insert 3 values for him .

But what i'm confuse is how can i make insert new Data . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMN3L.png)

Oke if you any link which refer about problem , and explain about it , you can directly comment it .

Comment: check this article http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/09/how-to-create-master-detail-entry-form-in-aspnet-mvc4.html?m=1 , the order detail in the article will be StudentGrade and orders will be the student table

Comment: It seems good tutorial , can you find me a good tutorial whic spesific to my problem?.

Comment: can you tell what is your issue here ? What is your EF query for the `save` ?

Comment: Siapa penemu bohlam dfdsaf